# PHP Paypal SDK - get 20 of the latest transactions

Tags: php, paypal

Hi I have the following code using PayPal PHP SDK:

```
    // Replace Mode to Live once Live 
    $pp_sdkConfig = array(
                "mode" => $mode
    );
        
            
    $pp_cred = new OAuthTokenCredential(
                $paypal_api_key,
                $paypal_secret
    );      


        
    $apiContext = new ApiContext($pp_cred); 
        
    $apiContext->setConfig(
     array(
         'mode' => $mode
     )
    );


     $access_token = $pp_cred->getAccessToken($pp_sdkConfig);

     $payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();


     $payments = ''; 

    try {

        $params = array('count' => 10, 'start_index' => 0);

        $payments = $payment->all($params, $apiContext);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) 
    {

    }
```

everything works, but if I change the count parameter from 10 to 20, it still only returns 10 entries, how cand I access more of the data?

I tried by changing the start_index from 0 to 10, but then I only get an empty array as response.

thx

Comment: I think the maximum you can use for count is 20. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_list I believe you will need to use 5 calls changing the start_index

Comment: 20 entries, would actually be OK, but my problem is no matter what I change i only get 10 entries as return value. when I change the start_index from 0 to 10, I get an empty array as response.